# Converting a c# get method a to post method, call from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, http-post

I have some c# api controllers which are current get() methods. I'd like to convert them all to post.
On the JavaScript side, I can see it's fairly straight forward, but need some guidance mostly in c#.

Here's my current get() method in c#:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Http;
using DynAggrClient;


namespace theapi.Controllers
{
    public class dimController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/dim/?sid=SID&values=T/F
        //
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            string sid = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "sid", "");
            int returnValues = 0;

            if (UrlUtil.getParam(this, "values", "F") == "T" )
                returnValues = 1;

            string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.dimRequest(sid, returnValues );

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(resp, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

and my current front end http call :

```js
function getDimensionsFromServer() {
 // fetch Dimensions list form server; 
 var rageVars = $rootScope.rageSessionVars;
 var returnValues = true;
 var url = "http://" + rageVars.domainName + ":" + rageVars.port + "/api/dim?sid=" + rageVars.sessionID + "&values=" + returnValues;
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 deferred.notify("Getting Dimensions...");
 $http({
  method: 'GET',
  encoding: 'JSON',
  headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true'
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  url: url
 }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  var retval = data;
  deferred.resolve(retval);
 });
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

And from what I'm researching so far on the JavaScript side, my http post request should look something like this :

```js
var sid = 'abf843945b6';
var url = 'http://localhost/api/dim';
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: url,
 headers: {
  'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { sid: sid },
}

$http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

But I'm in need of further advice on how to convert the c# get() method to post().

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

```js
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public class dimController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/dim/?sid=SID&values=T/F
        //
        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            string sid = Request.Form["sid"];
            int returnValues = 0;

            if (Request.Form["values"] == "T" )
                returnValues = 1;

            string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.dimRequest(sid, returnValues );

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(resp, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: question please. I want a post() method, but your answer still says Get().

Comment: The Request object does not have the Form() method on it. Am I missing a namespace ?